# How to Generate TouchEvent?

Tags: java, android

I Have drawn a set of images(balls) on a SurfaceView. Now am trying to make the image(ball) i touch to disappear. Am having those images in a collection. Am not understanding how to generate touch event on individual image. Can any one provide
some help on this?

Thank You
Yashwanth.B

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have an `ImageView`, you should implement the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Android utility "**sendevent**" to generate a touch event and should be able be found it at /system/bin/, if you know the coordinate of your image.

You also need to know the device node of your touch panel, assuming it is event1

```
/system/bin/sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330 1
/system/bin/sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 0 x
/system/bin/sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 1 y
/system/bin/sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
/system/bin/sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330 0
```

Here **x**, **y** represent your coordinate of your image.